# Line spacing does not go to zero

Tags: blogger, fonts

I have reduced the font size to very small [here](http://valjok.blogspot.com/2013/08/exploiting-exponential-curve.html) but large interline gaps remained. Additionally, it does not seem to be monospace since length does not increase monotonously as it should in case of font-family: "Courier New",Courier,monospace. In edit mode, everything is fine.

Comment: The line spacing is dependent on the `line-height`, not the `font-size` (although it is related initially).

Comment: Thanks. I have set the line-height to zero for the enclosing `<pre>` component. It does not change anything. Also, I see no problem in the editor mode where I just select a small font and all inter-line spacing to to zero with font size. I do not change line spacing separately. I ask here because line-height does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was that switching from HTML to WYSIWYG composition mode, blogger does something to the HTML so that `font-family: "Courier New",Courier,monospace; font-size: 1px;` slipped into `<pre>` tag where nothing more but font size had effect.